# Cannot change .NET MAUI Blazor Splash screen on IOS

Tags: ios, .net-maui

I have tried to follow all tutorials available about splash screens for .NET MAUI, but I can't have my app display a custom splash screen.
The steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 on a PC
2. Create a new .NET MAUI Blazor App project
3. Expand Resources\Splash folder
4. Replace splash.svg contents with the contents of a custom splash svg
5. Open a Mac
6. Pair to Mac  (Visual Studio -> Tools -> IOS)
7. Connect an iPhone to the PC USB port
8. Select IOS Local Devices/iPhone on Visual Studio targets dropdown
9. Change IOS/Bundle Signing Scheme to Automatic provisioning on Project properties
10. Launch the new app on the iPhone

It keeps showing the default .NET Splash screen instead of the custom one. The same issue happens with appIcon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is a bug in MAUI's resizetizer.

As a workaround, you need to actually provide a new name to the splash screen image (as well as the app icon), it cannot be named `splash.svg` if you want to change it. Everytime you change the image, you also need to provide an entirely new name due to a caching bug.

A fix is in the making, but ETA is unknown at the moment. Refer to this for the bug:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8685