# .net unable to change MauiIcon and MauiSplashScreen from .net purple defaults

Tags: splash-screen, maui, appicon

I've added new .svg images to the AppIcon and Splash directories and set the Build Action property on these to  MauiIcon and MauiSplashScreen this didn't work. Then searched for any references to the files themselves and found they were being referenced in the .csproj file. See below...

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\bridgerecordicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\bridgerecordsplash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

Neither of these two actions had a discernible effect.

The MS documentation ([text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)) says the following...

"
On iOS, the splash screen is added to the app package as a storyboard named MauiSplash.storyboard, which is set as value of the UILaunchStoryboardName key in the app package's Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  ...
  <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
  <string>MauiSplash</string>
  ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

Therefore, you shouldn't set the UILaunchStoryboardName key in your Info.plist file and you shouldn't add a LaunchScreen.storyboard to your app."

I've checked the MauiSplash.storyboard file and it appears to reference my updated splash image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file was auto-generated by .NET MAUI.-->
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Llm-lL-Icb"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xb3-aO-Qok"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="center" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" image="bridgerecordsplash.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aT4-1l-d9a">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.3176471" green="0.1686275" blue="0.8313726" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="{0}" />
    </resources>
</document>
```

However the Info.plist file does not appear to have the entry specified in the documentation...

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I manually added it, to test it out but that didn't help either. Can anyone give me a hint as to how to do this.

Also looked at this report [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334806/cannot-change-net-maui-blazor-splash-screen-on-ios), replaced the file with a new file. It seems to be relinked, however did not have a visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [Add a splash screen to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios), a splash screen can be added to your app project by dragging an image into the `Resources\Splash folder` of the project, where its build action will automatically be set to `MauiSplashScreen`. This creates a corresponding entry in your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\yourcustomscreen.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, on **iOS**, you shouldn't set the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key in your `Info.plist` file and you shouldn't add a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to your app as **iOS** easily produces storyboard errors.

Additionally, there's a known issue [Custom splash screens for per-platform scenarios #1222](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1222) on Github, you can follow up on it. As an alternative workaround, you can try to use [this workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12917#issuecomment-1405899251) provided by Marcel.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a while. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.